# How to convert HEIC image to JPG image in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, photosframework, heic

Im having NSData of Image type HEIC (photo taken from IOS 12), I need to convert HEIC to JPG and then add to Photo library(to phone having IOS 10.3). Since IOS 10.3 doesn't support of HEIC photo type i need to convert and add to library.
I have tried the following code but failed to add into library.
for converting i used.

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:imageData], 0.7);
```

as suggested in other threads. But when i add the resulted data to Photo library i am getting error as Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)".

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                        [[PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset] addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:imageData options:nil];
                    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        if (error) {
                            [weakSelf writeLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error on adding photo to photo album: %@",error.debugDescription]];
                        }
                        dispatch_semaphore_signal(weakSelf.savephoto);
                    }];
```

Comment: Like you said iOS 10 doesn't support HEIC so it can't convert it. You'll need to convert it using an external library

Comment: thanks for clarification, Any libraries suggested?